# How to stop tail -f except using kill

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

I want to write a shell script to detect if my program starts up successfully.

There is a log file created by the program. When the log file contains a new line: `Server startup in`, then stop the bash command.

I have found one solution with `kill`:

```
sh -c 'tail -f logfile | { sed "/Server startup in/ q" && kill $$ ;}'
```

But this is not working when I put it to my jenkins job, is there any other method to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
tail -f logfile | grep -q "Server startup in"
```

It will search for the string in `logfile` and `grep` exits silently after the first new line that contains the string appears. As soon as the command exits, the string is found and you can continue the script..

Comment: It's works, but I cannot see logfile content in terminal.

Comment: @Jason you could also use `grep -m 1 "Server startup in"`, that will also exit after 1 occurence, but it prints the occurence.